# I am getting value in variable c1.a=30 and c1=namspace_name.class_name, After nulling my object

Tags: c#, c#-2.0

```
class C
{
    int a;
    int c=10;
    void F(C c1)
    { 
        c1.a = 30;
        c1 = null;
    }

    public static void Main(string[]args)
    {
        C c1 = new C();
        c1.a = 10;
        c1.F(c1);          
        Console.WriteLine(c1.a);
        Console.WriteLine(c1);
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I implement Idisposable.dispose method to reclaim memory explicitly in my program.

Comment: It's very unclear what the issue is here, could you please explain what the problem is? Why are you doing `c1 = null`, does this code even compile?

Answer (score 1):

`c1` in your case is **not** an `alias` but a new local variable to which reference is passed by value..

So, `c1.a=55;` would work but `c1=null;` would only nullify the local variable c1 **not** your original variable..

---

To get the desired behaviour pass it by `reference`

```
c1.F(ref c1);
```

Your method should be

```
void F(ref C c1)
{ 
    c1.a = 30;
    c1 = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you are not "nulling" an object, you're nulling a reference to it. When you assign `c1 = null`, you only set one particular reference to that object to null while leaving the other reference (in `Main`) untouched.

Comment: Thank you Kviiri. One more thing How can I implement Idisposable interface in my class and dispose c1 object –

Answer (score 0):

I have renamed the parameter to "arrrgghhh" to show what is happening. You gave them both the same name, but that doesn't make them the same variable. They both point at the same object, but if you null arrrgghhh it doesn't null c1. c1 will still be pointing to the object even though arrrgghhh isn't anymore.

```
class C
{
    int a;
    int c=10;
    void F(C arrrgghhh)
    { 
        arrrgghhh.a = 30;
        arrrgghhh = null;
    }

    public static void Main(string[]args)
    {
        C c1 = new C();
        c1.a = 10;
        c1.F(c1);          
        Console.WriteLine(c1.a);
        Console.WriteLine(c1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Yutani. I am changing value in the obj which is same in main as well as in Fun. If I am nullyfy the obj in Fun than datamember inside the same object(c1=arrrgghhh) shud be null

Comment: you only null the reference to the object. you can't null objects themselves in c#. Both c1 and arrrgghhh point to the same object. By setting c1 to null you just clear the pointer to that object. arrggghh will still be pointing at it though.

Comment: Thank you Yutani. One more thing How can I implement Idisposable interface in my class and dispose c1 object